# On free direct summand locus of finitely generated modules over commutative Noetherian rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, schemes, affine-schemes, coherent-sheaves, quasicoherent-sheaves

Let $M$ be a finitely generated module over a commutative Noetherian ring $R$. Assume that there exists an injective $R$-linear morphism $f: R\to M$. Consider the sets $$U:=\{\mathfrak p\in \text{Spec}(R): R_{\mathfrak p} \text{ is a direct summand of some finite direct sum of copies of } M_{\mathfrak p}\}$$

$$V:=\{\mathfrak p\in \text{Spec}(R): R_{\mathfrak p} \text{ is a direct summand of  } M_{\mathfrak p}\}$$

$$W:=\{\mathfrak p\in \text{Spec}(R): f_{\mathfrak p}: R_{\mathfrak p} \to M_{\mathfrak p} \text{ is a split injection}\}$$

Clearly, $W\subseteq V\subseteq U$. I ask you to take me on faith that $U,V$ are Zariski open subsets of $\text{Spec}(R)$.
Consider the inclusion maps $i_U: U\to \text{Spec}(R)$, $i_W: W\to \text{Spec}(R)$, and $i_V: V\to \text{Spec}(R)$. By abuse of notation, I will denote the sheaf associated to $M$ on $\text{Spec}(R)$ just by $M$.

My questions are:

(1) If $U$ is  non-empty , then is $\mathcal O_U$ a direct summand of a finite direct sum of copies of $i_U^* M$ ?

(2)   If $V$ is  non-empty , then is $\mathcal O_V$ a direct summand of a finite direct sum of copies of $i_V^* M$ ?

(3) If $W$ is  non-empty , then is $\mathcal O_W$ a direct summand of a finite direct sum of copies of $i_W^* M$ ?

Comment: this question sounds like it is more suited for the MO site. This site is a student site.